# SSRS Report with variable static/non-static issues

Tags: reporting-services

Thanks in advance for looking at this.

I am trying to build a report that has data at the top and bottom that I need on every page. This is grouped by a couple of factors. Then, in the middle, based on the same grouping, I need a list that may contain anywhere from 1-20 items. This may mean it takes more than 1 page, and when it does, I need the top and bottom information to be matching on all of those pages. I have an image attached, where the yellow is static per page, and the green is grouped by same information, but grows in line count.

Is this possible? I currently have all of this set to inside of a list, with text boxes and a tablix. I have done this with only text boxes, but only get 1 'order' per page, and want to try to allow up to 4-5 orders per page with this. Thanks[image]
[image: rowgroups]

Comment: Does all the data come from a single dataset? Also, from your comments you have multiple orders per Patient (I assume) but do you have multiple Patients returned in you dataset of just data for 1 patient? Finally, do you have any rowgroups setup at the moment? This will affect how you need to design the report.

Comment: Single dataset, yes.
I do have multiple orders per patient, and multiple patients in 1 pull of the query.
Attaching an image of my current rowgroups